# How to access data inside a complex JSON object in Dart?

Tags: json, websocket, dart, flutter

I use a WebSocket to communicate to a server in my Flutter app. Let's say I receive a JSON object trough the WebSocket :

```
{
    "action": "getProduct",
    "cbackid": 1521474231306,
    "datas": {
        "product": {
            "Actif": 1,
            "AfficheQte": 0,
            "Article": "6"
        },
        "result": "success"
    },
    "deviceID": "4340a8fdc126bb59"
}
```

I have no idea what the content of `datas` will be until I read the `action`, and even then, it's not guaranteed to be the same every time. One example of a changing `action`/`datas` is when the product doesn't exist.

I can parse it in a `Map<String, Object>`, but then, how do I access what's inside the `Object`?

What's the correct way to read this data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what the question is about, but you can check the type of the values and then continue accordingly

```
if(json['action'] == 'getProduct') {
  var datas = json['datas'];
  if(datas is List) {
    var items = datas as List;
    for(var item in items) {
      print('list item: $item');
    }
  } else if (datas is Map) {
    var items = datas as Map;
    for(var key in items.keys) {
      print('map item: $key, ${items[key]}');
    }
  } else if(datas is String) {
    print('datas: $datas');
  } // ... similar for all other possible types like `int`, `double`, `bool`, ...
}
```

You also can make that recursive to check list or map values if they are `String`, ...